# don't show results for certain amount after getting results from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big issue. I have a booking page where I have a database with all the time slots. when I book in someone it books in the amount of slots depending on how long it takes. is there a way I can show available slots taking into account the how long it takes so it doesn't clash and overlapping of the next day.

```
    $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "grass";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, day, hour FROM availability WHERE booked='' and day >= CURDATE()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {




        $next = date("M jS ", strtotime("".$row["day"] .""));
        echo "<a class='button' style='margin:10px;' href=book_process.php?pageid=" . $row["id"] . "> <p style='font-size:20px; margin:0px;'>$next</p> <br> ". $row["hour"]. "</a>";

    }
} else {
    echo "You are booked up for the week";
}
$conn->close();
```

Additional information:
Each time slot is 15 minutes long. i have a users table and availability table. the users table has the many things about the user including. time_taken which contains how long it takes for that user. availability has all the times. name of the user and the time and date.

Basically, it searches the database for slots which are the exact number which I specify. the example I have a job labelled 5. another job takes 3. it needs to show slots 1 and 2., not 3 or 4 or 5 because it will clash with the other job.

Comment: need to see db schema and sample data

Comment: Please add sql fiddle, expected and actual results.